# I have exported some variables from a page and tried to import the variables. But it is not working

Tags: javascript

I have exported some variables from a page and tried to import the variables. But it is not working. I researched this issue but not found any solutions. I am using Mac Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100. Any help would be appreciated.

**export.js(http://localhost:8888/javascript/es6/export.js)**

```
"use strict";
export const foo = "bar";
export const bar = "foo";
```

**import.js(http://localhost:8888/javascript/es6/import.js)**

```
"use strict";
import { foo } from "export.js"
console.log(foo);
```

Result

**import.html(http://localhost:8888/javascript/es6/import.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="import.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the import syntax on normal `<script>` tags you need to add the `<script type="module">` attribute to it to enable importing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="import.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) script docs and MDN guide on modules [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules):

> **type** This attribute indicates the type of script represented. The
>   value of this attribute will be in one of the following categories:
>
> **module**: Causes the code to be treated as a JavaScript module. The
>   processing of the script contents is not affected by the charset and
>   defer attributes.

Comment: It's not working either. You get CORS error in Chrome browser .

Comment: @Noob then you need to add CORS headers in your dev server. But that is not the problem OP has asked about

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick Thank you so much. After added `type="module"`. Previous error gone `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. But I got another error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "export.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`  I resolved this error using `./`  before export.js. So `import.js` file script updated `import { foo } from "./export.js"`.

Comment: @SarathTS yes `"./" ` means get the file from the current level of the directory so I assume you have placed both `import.js ` and `export.js` in the same directory.